# How can I map controls of an existing Unity application, when no UI is provided?

Tags: unity, input, linux, configuration

I have an Unity application, that someone made for me in the past. It is provided as single binary file for Linux in this case.
It features a very simple "launcher" which let me select the resolution (made by Unity I guess?) and then starts into the application without any further UI or splash screen. Which is fine.

However, while it was originally made for joystick input (needs one axis only), there is only keyboard control working. I guess the joystick must be assigned somehow to the controllable axis.

So how can I do that by command line or providing config files, as there is no UI for that in the application?

Comment: I doubt it is possible. If you don't have the source available, you don't know how the binding was done. There are two different input systems, it could be done by code or editor. It might be possible to inject some code with a rebinding. Easiest would be to ask for the code or redo the app

Comment: This might be technically possible using a hex editor to find the bytes in the compiled executable / data blobs that describe the mapping and change them to new magic numbers. Or to find the byte that controls whether to show the input mapping tab at start-up and change it. I don't know of any source that has done this reverse engineering though, amd it's a hefty task for a volunteer to take on, so you might be on your own. As Zibelas says, reaching out to the original creator for the source files or a modification would likely be easier and more reliable.

Comment: Aww. I was forced to do something like that in the past for some Unreal project, and in the end it was just text configuration there. Editing into the binary sounds like trouble. As the "content" and "configuration" is just compressed to the binary, is there not any standard tool that would extract or repack it?